# SQL query sort by count() from a different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm performing ajax request using jQuery bootstrap table... Using the following query to fetch the websites list:

```
SELECT * 
FROM websites 
WHERE (name LIKE '%xx%' OR url LIKE '%xx%' OR country LIKE '%xx%') 
ORDER BY id desc 
LIMIT 0,10
```

I need to able to sort websites by the number of articles each website has in a table called articles (including WHERE clause) in asc or desc as required. I can get count using following queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM articles 
WHERE website_url='$url' 
AND DATE(date_inserted) = CURRENT_DATE 
AND is_valid='1'

SELECT * 
FROM articles 
WHERE website_url='$url' 
AND is_valid='1'
```

Both tables have a common field which could be used to match: in websites table, it's called 'url' and in articles table it's called 'website_url'

Also note that I need to fetch a limited number of websites at a time but the result should be sorted according to ALL rows present in the table.

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm clueless how to build the required query.

> Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=4UG71ov2Jz

Comment: Questions about MySQL should atleast include a `SHOW CREATE TABLE [table]` for every table involved and example data as ascii data table but best is to provide a sqlfiddle.com or a db-fiddle.com... Also a ascii data table with expected result is also handy.. This way we can better help you

Comment: @RaymondNijland you should make your comment more generic. not only MySQL need those.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I've added the fiddle.

Comment: You didnt include your desire ouput with that data

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Solved already. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT w.*
  FROM websites w
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT website_url, COUNT(*) as num_articles
                     FROM articles
                    WHERE is_valid='1'
                    GROUP BY website_url) a
    ON a.website_url = w.url
 WHERE (w.name LIKE '%xx%' OR w.url LIKE '%xx%' OR w.country LIKE '%xx%')
 ORDER BY a.num_articles DESC
 LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: I'm sorry, in the website table, the common field is called 'url' instead of 'website_url'. I have corrected this.

Comment: Works like a charm!